# Socket issue, client claiming it failed to connect, but server says it did

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I've run into a problem when running my server on a remote PC that is connected to the same network.

I manage to connect client to server, but the client throws an exception saying it failed to open socket; on the server side, though, I see that client did indeed connect, and I can send messages from client to server, but not from server to client.

Here is the server side to start a server.

```
private void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.150", 3333));
            _serverSocket.Listen(5);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            textBox.Text += "Waiting for connections\r\n";
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I have opened a port in my router for 3333 UDP/TCP as well on that IP.

Here is client connecting code.

```
void Connect()
{
            try
            {
                _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.150"), 3333), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);

                _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), _clientSocket);
                AppendToTextBox("Connected!");
            }
            catch
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to open socket!");
            }
}
```

When I run both on my machine, everything works flawlessly, but when I try to do it remotely, it fails; however, since I'm able to send messages to the server from the client, and not vice versa I'm kinda confused about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `BeginReceive` will raise an exception. This is because the `BeginConnect` isn't ready yet.

It might run localhost, because the `BeginConnect` could be ready before calling `BeginReceive` but I wouldn't bet on it.

This is **NOT** gonna work:

```
_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.150"), 3333), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);

_clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), _clientSocket);

AppendToTextBox("Connected!");
```

You must call the `BeginReceive` after/in the `ConnectCallback`. Also you cannot assume that after BeginReceive is called, the socket is directly connected.

---

It should be something like:  **(PSEUDO)**

```
public void Start()
{
    _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _clientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.5.150"), 3333), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
}

public void ConnectCallback(IASyncResult state)
{
    // get the socket from the state etc.....
    AppendToTextBox("Connected!");

    clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), _clientSocket);
}

public void RecieveCallback(IASyncResult state)
{
    // check if you receive the bytes you are trying to read.
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that thing, Jezz.. Thanks a lot! That did the trick!